# Java like statement of condition?a:b in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ternary

Is there a way to make the `print_str` function be more concise and becomes one line?

```
   def print_str(str):
        if len(str)>0:
            print(str + ", "+ "hi")
        else:
            print("hi")

   if __name__ == '__main__':
        print_str(("John"))
        print_str((""))
```

In java we can do something like

```
print(str + (str.equals("") ? "" : ", ") + "hi");
```

Comment: Note: don't name variables `str`. That's a builtin python method/type

Comment: Also, you don't need `if len(str)>0:`, just do `if str:`. Empty collections (including strings) are falsey; non-empty ones are truthy.

Comment: Also, why the extra parens around the arguments to `print_str`? They aren't doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do something similar in a one line `if else` statement with python. In your example it would be like this:

```
print(str + ("" if str == "" else ", ") + "hi")
```

The format is `X if condition else Y` where `X` is the result if the condition is true and `Y` is the result otherwise.

Comment: Or `print(str + ",hi" if len(str) > 0 else "hi")`

Comment: @cricket_007: Or just test `str` instead of `len(str) > 0` or `not str` instead of `str == ""` following [the PEP8 recommendation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): "For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false", which explicitly `if seq` and `if not seq` as preferable to any test involving `len`.